# Functional analysis: Why $p(x)\leq\inf\{p_{a_1}\mid x_1\in F_{a_1}, x=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ a set of index and $E$ an $\mathbb F$ vector space. For each $a\in A$, let $F_a$ be a vector space and $\mathcal T_a$ the topology induced by the set of seminorms $\Gamma_a$. Furthermore, let $G_a:F_a\to E$ be a linear map. Suppose that $E=\bigcup_{a\in A}G_a(F_a).$

$(E,\mathcal T)$ is defined by the set of seminorms $\Gamma$ such that $p:E\to\mathbb R$ in $\Gamma$ if $\forall a\in A, p\circ G_a$ is a continuous seminorm on $F_a$.

We remark that $p:E\to \mathbb R$ is in $\Gamma$ if
$$\forall a\in A,\exists s\in(\Gamma_a)_f,\exists \lambda>0: p\circ G_a\leq \lambda s.$$

Let define $\hat\Gamma$ by $p\in\hat\Gamma$ if
$$p(x)=\inf\left\{\sum_{j=1}^n p_{a_j}(x_j)\mid n\in\mathbb N, a_j\in A\text{ and }x_j\in F_{a_j}\text{ for all }j\in\{1,...,n\},x=\sum_{j=1}^n G_{a_j}(x_j)\right\}$$

Where for all $a\in A$, $p_a$ is a continuous seminorm on $F_a$. We want to show that $\hat \Gamma\subset \Gamma$. Let $p_a$ for $a\in A$ and $p\in\hat\Gamma$ like above. Let $a_1$ be fixed. I don't understand why
$$p(x)\leq\inf\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1}, x=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}$$
and
$$p(G_{a_1}(z_1))\leq \inf\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1},G_{a_1}(z_1)=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}\leq p_{a_1}(z_1)$$
for all $z_1\in F_{a_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea here is to use the following properties of the infimum. Namely, if $\emptyset\neq U\subset V$ and $f\colon V \to W$, then we have
$$\inf_{x\in V}f(x)\leq\inf_{x\in U}f(x) \qquad \text{and}\qquad \inf_{x\in U}f(x)\leq f(u) \quad \forall u \in U.$$

---

In your case:

Note that
$$D_1:=\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1}, x=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}\quad\subset\quad \{p_{a}(x_1)\mid a\in A, x_1\in F_{a_1}, x=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}\\ \subset D_p:=\left\{\sum_{j=1}^n p_{a_j}(x_j)\mid n\in\mathbb N, a_j\in A\text{ and }x_j\in F_{a_j}\text{ for all }j\in\{1,...,n\},x=\sum_{j=1}^n G_{a_j}(x_j)\right\}.$$

So that 
$$p(x)=\inf\{t \mid t \in D_p\}\overset{D_1\subset D_p}{\leq} \inf\{t \mid t \in D_1\}=\inf\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1}, x=G_{a_1}(x_1)\} \qquad (*)$$
and your first inequality follows.
To get
$$p(G_{a_1}(z_1))\leq \inf\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1},G_{a_1}(z_1)=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}$$
just plug $x=G_{a_1}(z_1)$ in $(*)$. Finally, since
$$p_{a_1}(z_1)\in \{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1},G_{a_1}(z_1)=G_{a_1}(x_1)\},$$
(remember that $z_1\in F_{a_1}$) we must have
$$\inf\{p_{a_1}(x_1)\mid x_1\in F_{a_1},G_{a_1}(z_1)=G_{a_1}(x_1)\}\leq p_{a_1}(z_1).$$